# exe export from visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, exe

Is there any way how to compile my c++ project in VS12 to exe with all the dll imports (like GLUT) and media files like images/sounds. I need just 1 exe file, that will be working on every computer even if there is not GLUT installed. (ps I know that in debug file is exe but that one is not working without installed glut) thanks

Comment: Are you using C++ "native" or C++/CLI (=.NET) ? Do you have the source of all dependencies (DLLs...) ?

Comment: Then you will need to compile all dependencies not as DLLs but as real libraries (.LIB)... the linker is then able to link all code together... as for your additional file (images/sounds) you will need to "embed them as resources" and load them at runtime - depending on how you use them you might need to write them to "real files" at runtime... all this will need a bit of code changes...

Comment: You are probably right but I have no idea how to do it :D, Can u be more concrete plz?

Comment: My problem is that you don't provide any concrete information... source code would be helpful...

Comment: source code has more than 800 lines but here you have all imports of libraries and example how I load the texture
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include "Vector.h"


hBMP=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "texture0.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE );

Comment: If I figure out how to import these glut files I will be more than happy, I have glut32.dll and glut32.lib files, but unfortunatelly I dunno what to do with them...

Comment: sorry but it is really hard to tell you anything specific: glut32.lib might be a static/real library (which would mean you just need to setup your project to use that instead of the DLL) BUT it could just an "import library" (=stub) which is only needed to get the wiring between your project and the DLL right...